# summary report on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, custom-report-type

can any one help me out in this.I have created a custom visual force page on "quote " object in a PDF format where the data gets displayed .Now Can we create a summary Report like data with subtotal and grandtotals in a visual force page in a PDF format.Any suggestion plz.

Using an tag as and passing a hard core value in a Visualforce page in a PDF.

```
<analytics:reportChart ReportId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" showRefreshButton="true" size="huge" cacheResults="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if all of the values or components of the values you need exist in the database. You will need to write your own controller and own Visualforce page with renderAs="pdf". [SOQL Aggregate functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) give you the ability to summarize data with functions such as SUM. The feasibility of this is dependent on your data set size. If it is larger than the governor limits will allow for your query, you may have to summarize the data in a batch job first.

Another alternative is to use the [Salesforce1 Reporting API in Apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_analytics_intro.htm) (formerly known as Analytics API via Apex).  With this, you can create the summary report that you want and then query the data in your Apex controller. There is support for summary reports in the API.