# On wrapper class can we get the subtotals and grandtotals calculation in a table at footer ,VF page in PDF

Tags: visualforce

can any one help me out in this.I have created a custom visual force page on "quote " object in a PDF format where the data gets displayed .Now Can we create a we get the subtotals and grand totals calculation in a table at footer in a visual force page in a PDF format.Any suggestion plz.

SOQL Query using as : GROUP BY CUBE or  GROUP BY ROLLUP

[image]

Comment: Nikkey, please update your first question (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65635/summary-report-on-visual-force-page) . Re-posting a question to get more attention is'nt a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I often come back to this old example as it has pagination and covers most of what you want

[PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce)